# DRY with almost similiar functions and arguments

Tags: python-2.7, function

I've got a function call that I'm making to a library that looks something like:

```
some_function(var1=x,var2=y)
```

The same library has another function which makes a similar call but to a sandbox:

```
some_test_function(var1=x,var2=y)
```

I *could* just write:

```
if sandbox:
    some_test_function(var1=x,var2=y)
else:
    some_function(var1=x,var2=y)
```

but, I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.  In particular, can I define a dictionary as {'var1':x,'var2':y} and pass it in to the correct function?  My psuedo-code would be something like:

```
dict = {'var1':x,'var2':y}
function_name = 'some_test_function' if sandbox else 'some_function'
function_name(dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any functions you create will have their names stored in the `locals()` builtin dictionary. So you can get access to a method by name, e.g.:

```
sandbox = True

def some_function(x, y):
  print(x, y)

def some_test_function(x, y):
  print("test", x, y)


function_name = "some_function"
if sandbox:
    function_name = "some_test_function"

locals()[function_name]('cat', 'dog')
# test cat dog
```

Note: If these are functions in a class, then you should look as `getattr()` which performs a similar task.